# Change row order in a matrix/dataframe

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I need to change/invert rows in my data frame, not transposing the data but moving the bottom row to the top and so on. If the data frame was:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I need to convert to

```
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

I've read about `sort()` but I don't think it is what I need or I'm not able to find the way.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There probably are more elegant ways, but this works:

```
m <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

# m[rev(seq_len(nrow(m))), ]  # Initial answer
m[nrow(m):1, ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    8    9
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    1    2    3
```

---

This works because you are indexing the matrix with a reversed sequence of integers as the row index.  `nrow(m):1` results in `3 2 1`.

Answer (score 28):

You can reverse the order of a data.frame using the `dplyr` package:

```
iris %>% arrange(-row_number())
```

Or without using the pipe-operator by doing

```
arrange(iris, -row_number())
```

Comment: Or `iris[order(row.names(iris), decreasing = T),]`

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar I think your solution is less intuitive because it has a "orphan" comma, specifies the table of interest twice, and is mixing round and square brackets. I know that this is correct base-r syntax but it lacks some elegance in my taste.

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar actually this won't work correctly because `row.number`s are actually `character`s. You will need to to convert `integer` first as in `iris[order(as.integer(row.names(iris)), decreasing = TRUE),]`

Comment: Or `iris %>% arrange(desc(row_number()))`

Answer (score 8):

I would reverse the rows an index starting with the number of rows, along this line

```
revdata <-  thedata[dim(thedata)[1L]:1,]
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this is the simplest way:

```
MyMatrix = matrix(1:20, ncol = 2)
MyMatrix[ nrow(MyMatrix):1, ]
```

If you want to reverse the columns, just do

```
MyMatrix[ , ncol(MyMatrix):1 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

We can reverse the order of row.names (for data.frame only):

```
# create data.frame
m <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
df_m <- data.frame(m)

#reverse
df_m[rev(rownames(df_m)), ]

#   X1 X2 X3
# 3  7  8  9
# 2  4  5  6
# 1  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Veeery late, but this seems to be working fast, does not need any extra packages and is simple:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(matrix)) {matrix[,i] = rev(matrix[,i])}
```

I guess that for frequent use, one would make a function out of it.
Tested with R v=3.3.1.

Comment: The vectorized solutions using `dplyr::arrange` or some form of `seq` are generally recommended, because R is optimized for vector operations as opposed to loops. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7146480/2575374) also does not rely on any extra packages.

Answer (score 1):

Encounter this problem today and here I am providing another solution for your interests.

```
m <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)    
apply(m,2,rev)
```